# Prob. on Hebrew encoding

Tags: c#, character-encoding, hebrew, unicode-string

I have a hebrew text just as `"×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں"`, and I want to convert it to readable unicode hebrew charackters.

I tried this code:

```
const string Str = "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں";

Encoding enc1 = Encoding.Default;
Encoding enc2 = Encoding.Unicode;

byte[] bytes = enc1.GetBytes(Str);

string hebrewString = enc2.GetString(bytes);

label1.Text = hebrewString;
```

But it didn't succeeded. Please Help.

**Update**
the text come from html source code

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:000000210
EndHTML:000006218
StartFragment:000001595
EndFragment:000006126
StartSelection:000001595
EndSelection:000006126
SourceURL:file:///C:/ProgramData/Babylon/LocalUI/wnd.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-    html401-19991224/loose.dtd">

<HTML 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD><TITLE>CLient build #1.2</TITLE><LINK 
rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="img/frame.css?ver=41"><LINK rel=stylesheet 
type=text/css href="img/baby.css?ver=41"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="img/word.css?ver=41"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="img/text.css?ver=41">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/moudles.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/extrnl.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/frame.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/word.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/fTxt.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/baby.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="js/plcy.js?ver=100"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY style="FONT-FAMILY: Verdana" onload=bodyLoad() 
class="scrollBar ie7 fontSize5" bgColor=#000100 name="Rslt">

<DIV class=m2>

<DIV class=mrg>

<DIV style="BOTTOM: -67px" id=baseBody class=client>

<DIV id=wordContainer>

<DIV style="OVERFLOW-Y: scroll; DISPLAY: block; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma" 
id=resultContainer class=wordBody>

<DIV id=rsltCntnr>

<DIV style="CURSOR: auto" id=BABID_Results><!--StartFragment--><DIV id=BABIDPtr_!!Z8UVKYSMBJ class=result entryType="3" entryPrio="1100099960">
<TABLE style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed" class=res-head cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=3 
width="100%">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top width=20><IMG id=BABID_CPIconImg class=BAB_ImgInTitle 
src="C:\Users\Mahmoud\AppData\Roaming\Babylon\Content\icons/Z8UVKYSMBJ_glossary_icon.ico"> 
</TD>
<TD id=BABID_CPTitle vAlign=top>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: inline" id=BABID_CPName class=BAB_NormalTitle>×‍ض´×œض¼×•ض¹×ں 
×گض¶×‘ض¶×ںض¾×©×پ×•ض¹×©×پض¸×ں ×”ض·×‍ض¼ض¸×œضµ×گ</DIV><SPAN style="PADDING-LEFT: 2px"     id=BABID_CPBandBtns 
valign="top"><IMG class=BAB_ImageBtn title="Dictionary menu" tabIndex=0 
src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\btn_titlemenu.png" 
behavetype="3ImageState" bab_name="BTN_TitleMenu"> 
</SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<DIV id=BABID_CPResult class=BAB_CPBodyStyleLocal>
<DIV xmlns:babex="urn:schemas-babylon-com:babex" 
xmlns:bab="urn:schemas-babylon-com:bab" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<DIV dir=rtl class=term align=right>
<DIV style="FLOAT: right" dir=ltr class=btnArr><IMG class=BAB_ImageBtn 
title="Previous term" tabIndex=0 
src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\btn_browseprevious.png" 
bab_name="BTN_BrowsePrevious" behaveType="3ImageState" baburi=""><IMG 
class=BAB_ImageBtn title="Next term" tabIndex=0 
src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\btn_browsenext.png" 
bab_name="BTN_BrowseNext" behaveType="3ImageState" baburi=""></DIV>×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں
<DIV class=rsltSpkrCntnr><IMG class=BAB_ImageBtn 
title="To listen to a text, select it, and click the speaker button" tabIndex=0 
src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\btn_sayit_rtl.png" valign="bottom" 
bab_name="BTN_SayIt_rtl" behaveType="3ImageState" baburi="" 
term="×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں"></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class=definition align=right><SPAN dir=rtl>
<STYLE>a{cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;color:blue</STYLE>

<DIV 
style="LINE-HEIGHT: 160%; FONT-FAMILY: David,Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 130%" 
dir=rtl><FONT style="COLOR: black; FONT-WEIGHT: normal"><SUP>×ھ</SUP></FONT> 
<FONT color=blue>(×–')</FONT> [×™×•×•× ×™×ھ: ariston] ×،ض°×¢×•ض¼×“ض¸×”, ×گض²×¨×•ض¼×—    ض¸×”: "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں 
×¢ض¸×ھض´×™×“ ×”ض·×§ض¼ض¸×“×•ض¹×©×پ-×‘ض¼ض¸×¨×•ض¼×ڑض°-×”×•ض¼×گ ×œض·×¢ض²×©×‚×•ض¹×ھ ×œض·×¢ض²    ×‘ض¸×“ض¸×™×• ×”ض·×¦ض¼ض·×“ض¼ض´×™×§ض´×™×‌ ×œض¶×¢ض¸×ھض´×™×“ 
×œض¸×‘×•ض¹×گ" (×•×™×§×¨×گ ×¨×‘×” ×™×’). "×گض²× ض´×™ ×¢×•ض¹×¨ضµ×ڑض° ×”ض¸×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں     ×œض·×—ض²×‘ض´×™×‘ض·×™, ×›ض¼ض·× ض°×¤ضµ×™ ×”ض¸×¨ض¹×ں" 
(×©×‍×¢×•× ×™, ×©×™×¨×™×‌ ×’ ×¤×”).
<P>[×گض²×¨ض´×™×،ض°×کض´×™×ں] </P></DIV></SPAN></DIV><BR 
style="CLEAR: both; FONT-SIZE: 1px"></DIV>
<DIV class=BAB_CPCopyrightStyle xmlns:babex="urn:schemas-babylon-com:babex" 
xmlns:bab="urn:schemas-babylon-com:bab" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"><BR><BR><BR>
<DIV dir=rtl>
<P><BR><BR>آ© ×›×œ ×”×–×›×•×™×•×ھ ×©×‍×•×¨×•×ھ ×œ×™×•×¨×©×™ ×”×‍×—×‘×¨<BR>Copyright 2003, The     author's 
heirs آ©</P><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<LI><B>×œ×”×§×“×‍×”, ×œ×”×،×‘×¨×™×‌, ×œ×¨×©×™×‍×ھ ×”×‍×§×•×¨×•×ھ ×•×¢×•×“ - ×¨×گ×• <A 
style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" 
href="bword://×‍ض´×œض¼×•ض¹×ں ×گض¶×‘ض¶×ںض¾×©×پ×•ض¹×©×پض¸×ں ×”ض·×‍ض¼ض¸×œضµ×گ/">×‍ض´×œض¼×•ض¹×ں     ×گض¶×‘ض¶×ںض¾×©×پ×•ض¹×©×پض¸×ں ×”ض·×‍ض¼ض¸×œضµ×گ 
- ×¢ض·×‍ض¼×•ض¼×“ضµ×™ ×”ض·×¤ض¼ض°×ھض´×™×—ض¸×”</A>.</B></LI></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" dir=rtl id=BABID_BottomLinks 
xmlns:babex="urn:schemas-babylon-com:babex" 
xmlns:bab="urn:schemas-babylon-com:bab" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<DIV style="FLOAT: left" id=BABID_BottomActions></DIV> <BR 
style="CLEAR: both; FONT-SIZE: 1px"></DIV>
<DIV class=prcTrial xmlns:babex="urn:schemas-babylon-com:babex" 
xmlns:bab="urn:schemas-babylon-com:bab" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<DIV class=left-corner><IMG class=BAB_ImageStat 
src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\trialcornerleft.png" width=4 
height=55 bab_name="TrialCornerLeft"></DIV>
<DIV style="BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%" 
class=right-corner><IMG class=BAB_ImageStat 
src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\trialcornerright.png" width=4 
height=55 bab_name="TrialCornerRight"></DIV>
<DIV class=prcTrial-body>
<DIV class=days-left>Dictionary trial version (4 days)</DIV><IMG 
class=BAB_ImageStat src="c:\programdata\babylon\localui\img\res\prctrial.png" 
bab_name="PRCTrial"><SPAN class=buy-link><A id=CP_LINK 
href="buyprc://!!Z8UVKYSMBJ,745,0/">Buy This 
Dictionary</A></SPAN></DIV></DIV></DIV><BR 
style="CLEAR: both; FONT-SIZE: 1px"></DIV><!--EndFragment--></DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

this html works fine, but I can't get the hebrew text to string
Thanks

Comment: That looks like Arabic, not Hebrew.

Comment: Where does the text come from? What encoding is it originally in? How are you reading it in?

Comment: .Net strings are always UTF16 LE, whatever system you run on, whatever the content of the string. Your font may not be able to display a unicode code point in a string. Your keyboard may not be able to type the desired charachter but, if the glyph is part of the unicode standard it can be represented in a .net string. If your default encoding is not unicode then all your code does is strip data from the string.

Comment: Thats because the my default system langauge is Arabic, but the text is Hebrew

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: OK. How are you reading the HTML source into your application? Do you know what encoding it uses to begin with?

Comment: I just copied this HTML to empty ANSII file and with name hebrew.html by NotePad, and it works fine

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, does it?

Comment: As you see in my question I copied and paste part of the text (ANSII) to the IDE to make a test

Comment: Well, that's not Hebrew. You need to open the file using the correct encoding.

Comment: I will try, although I think that the text is unicode because the repeat of "x" in the text "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں"

Comment: I'll try to explain. The file has been saved in a certain encoding (meaning, each set of bytes corresponds to a specific character, depending on the encoding). You need to open the file in the _same_ encoding, or you will not get the correct characters. Try using Notepad++ and using the `Encoding` menu try different Unicode and Hebrew encodings till you see proper Hebrew.

Comment: hehe Thanks with NotePad++ I chose UTF-8 and I could see the hebrew chars..  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. the text is utf-8

```
       const string Str = "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں";
        Encoding defaultEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        byte[] bytes = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(Str);
        Encoding encoding2 = Encoding.UTF8;
        string hebrewString2 = encoding2.GetString(bytes);
        label1.Text = hebrewString2;
```

Thanks for every body

Comment: For the curious (me), the Hebrew string is "אָרִיסְטוֹן" - a kitchen appliance brand name, with diacritics.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems you `Str` is not a valid Hebrew string.

Checking some possible encodings it seems it's a `Hebrew (Windows)`:

```
 const string Str = "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں";

 Encoding origionEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256); //assume the string was encoded as arabic

 byte[] bytes = origionEncoding.GetBytes(Str);

 Encoding desEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);       //Hebrew (Windows) 

 string hebrewString = desEncoding.GetString(bytes);
```

**EDIT:** It seems an Hebrew string has been encoded as Arabic encoding so to do the reverse (If possible) we should try possible origin/destination pairs of [encodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

Comment: the prob still exists and the result "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں"

Comment: @JustMe - It's important to know how the text comes into the program to begin with. If you start up with it being read incorrectly, it is difficult (or almost impossible) to correct the issue.

Comment: @Oded, true, once you strip the data by misusing encoding your going to have some blanks to fill in.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Thanks very much for your efforts, the text is utf-8 I update it to             const string Str = "×گض¸×¨ض´×™×،ض°×ک×•ض¹×ں";
            Encoding defaultEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            byte[] bytes = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(Str);
            Encoding encoding2 = Encoding.UTF8;
            string hebrewString2 = encoding2.GetString(bytes);
            label1.Text = hebrewString2;
and it works fine, please update your answer to approve it as the correct answer

Comment: and the result is "אָרִיסְטוֹן"

Comment: @JustMe It was your own effort. You can answer your own post and mark it as the correct answer.